# Change shader from grayscale to transparent

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am not a shader person, i have 1 shader available that can turn images in Unity Engine black and white, now i want to fix this shader to be transparent.
Can anyone help me ?
Thanks!!!

```
Shader "Hidden/Desaturate"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "black" {}
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {
            ZTest Always Cull Off ZWrite Off
            Fog { Mode off }

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert_img
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
            uniform float _Brightness;

            fixed4 frag (v2f_img i) : COLOR
            {
                float4 mainColor = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                float3 greyScale = dot(mainColor.rgb, float3(0.3, 0.59, 0.11)) * _Brightness;
                mainColor.rgb = greyScale;

                return mainColor;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }

    Fallback off
}
```

I want to change my greyscale shader to transparent shader

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this would help.

```
Shader "Hidden/Desaturate"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "black" {}
        //Remove property below if not needed
        _Brightness ("Brightness", Range(0,1)) = 1
    }

    SubShader
    {
        //This string was missed
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Pass
        {
            ZTest Always Cull Off ZWrite Off
            Fog { Mode off }

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert_img
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
            uniform float _Brightness;

            fixed4 frag (v2f_img i) : COLOR
            {
                float4 mainColor = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                float3 greyScale = dot(mainColor.rgb, float3(0.3, 0.59, 0.11)) * _Brightness;
                //Comment the line below if you want keep image colors
                mainColor.rgb = greyScale;
                mainColor.a = greyScale;
                return mainColor;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }

    Fallback off
}
```